# Google Maps Static Image not showing up (Android Browser)

Tags: android, html, google-maps, mobile, jquery-mobile

I'm using MetroWEB to test a mobile page that I'm working on which uses jQuery Mobile 1.1 as the framework.

You can find the page in question at: [Callaro's Mobile - Location](http://www.callarossteakhouse.com/_mobi/location.html)

Now, I've really never done a mobile page before so I'm basically learning as I go here. In any event, my problem is that my Google Maps Static Image is not showing up at all on my mobile browser.  All I see is a giant white square with a blue question mark in the middle.

I followed the API instructions to the T (or at least I think I did). The direct link to the Maps image and the img tag work perfectly on my desktop.  Anyone have any idea where the functionality is breaking here?

The img tag is constructed as follows:

```
<img width="300" height="300" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=717+Lake+Ave,Lake+Worth,FL&zoom=14&size=300x300&scale=2&markers=color:red|label:C|717+Lake+Ave,Lake+Worth,FL&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyCuOjnPNvw0HZhIWt0yQEeeXQn-GKfi7k8" style="display:block;width:300px;height:300px;margin:auto;" />
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!